# How do I combine two arrays in Java like you can combine them in Python?

Tags: python, java, dynamic-programming

I found the Dynamic Programming solution to the Coin Change problem in Python.

```html
def change(coins, amount):
    result = [amount+1] * (amount+1)
    coins_results = [[] for _ in range(amount+1)]

    result[0] = 0

    for i in range(1, amount+1):
        for coin in coins:
            if i >= coin and result[i - coin] + 1 < result[i]:
                result[i] = result[i-coin] + 1
                coins_results[i] = coins_results[i-coin] + [coin]
                

    if result[amount] == amount+1:
        return []

    return coins_results[amount]
```

However, when I try to transfer it to Java, I found some difficulties in this line.

```html
coins_results[i] = coins_results[i-coin] + [coin]
```

In java, it does not allow to directly combine two arrays or add one element in the array.
I have tried different ways but no luck. Could anyone give some help? Thank you

Comment: That line is building a new list by adding a new coin to another list. This can certainly be done in Java. Look up the `List` interface.  You'll use the constructor to make the copy and then `add()` to append the single coin.

Comment: Hi Gene, do you mean to transfer the array to List, add the coin, then transfer the list back to array?

Comment: I couldn't explain in comments, so added an answer.

Comment: Do you use array or array list?

Comment: I used array. It cannot simply be added an element. This is why I asked this problem, I aim to find a solution to achieve the same action in Python that listC = listA + listB.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, using `ArrayList`, which is essentially the same as Python `List`, the exact equivalent of the line you gave would be

```
coins_results[i] = new ArrayList<>(coins_results[i - coin]);
coins_results[i].add(coin);
```

I'm not claiming this is a great way to implement this DP, but for homework it should be fine.

You'll need to study the Java language harder. It's quite different from Python.

Comment: Thank you, Gene. I have already resolved this problem by another similar solution of using ArrayList as intermediate storage. 
I can understand what you mean here. After implementing these two lines of code in your answer, it doesn't work as the IDE reminds me for the second line: Cannot invoke add(int) on the array type int[].
Although I have resolved this problem, I'm still interested to figure out your answer. Could you please check and update the code so that I can better understand Array, ArrayList in Java?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend that you read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on writing good questions here. Your title is too broad and will discourage people from clicking on your question. I would recommend something like "How do I combine two arrays in Java like you can combine them in Python" You can edit your own question to make improvements like this.

You are correct in saying that you cannot combine two arrays/ add one element in Java. This is because java arrays are static, and can only store the number of elements they are defined to have.

You can instead use something from the `List` interface as Gene said. I would recommend using an `ArrayList`. This [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-in-java/) has a lot of good information and code examples for using them. Here are a couple of examples that will cover pretty much everything you would need for this problem.

```java
// This creates a new ArrayList 
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

// This adds elements to the ArrayList
arrayList.add(100);

// This gets elements from a list (similar to array[index])
arrayList.get(0);
arrayList.get(0) = 200;

// You can also add an entire list to the ArrayList
arrayList.addAll(someOtherList);

// Lastly, you can create nested ArrayLists by setting the type to another ArrayList
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nestedArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew. My problem was resolved. Although I have almost taken one year to study and work on Java, including uni's homework, projects, some backend development (Spring) in my internship, I found that I still don't fully understand many points in Java.